# Pandas apply function on each row with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column, `code` that is of type `int`. I would like to extract the last 5 digits for rows where length of this field is > 5. Sample data and my attempt below:

```
df['Code']

144    602000
145    602000
146    602000
147    602000
148    602000
        ...  
571    84410
572    84410
573    84410
574    84410
575    684410


df['Code5'] = df['Code'].apply(lambda row: row['Code'].astype(str).str[-5:] if len(row['Code']) > 5 else row['Code'])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You're using `Series.apply` the lambda "row" is the int values from the Series like `602000`. It would be clearer to use something like `lambda code: `. As an aside to the current Error you could just do `df['Code'] = df['Code'].astype(str).str[-5:]` since in python if you index outside of bounds it will give you as much as possible. So you don't need to check the length at all.

Comment: row is an integer. you can try str(row)[-5: ] instead of astype method.

Comment: If you wanted a number and not a string you could also do modulus: `df['Code'] = df['Code'] % 100_000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Code5'] = df['Code'].astype(str).str[-5:]
```

```
>>> df
       Code  Code5
144  602000  02000
145  602000  02000
146  602000  02000
147  602000  02000
148  602000  02000
571   84410  84410
572   84410  84410
573   84410  84410
574   84410  84410
575  684410  84410
999    1234   1234  # <- I added this sample
```

Another option is to fill value with less than 5 digits:

```
>>> df['Code'].astype(str).str[-5:].str.zfill(5)
144    02000
145    02000
146    02000
147    02000
148    02000
571    84410
572    84410
573    84410
574    84410
575    84410
999    01234  # <- padded with fillchar '0'
Name: Code, dtype: object
```

Comment: @kms. Did you have time to test the code?